# Puppet Error: Duplicate definition

Tags: ruby, puppet

In a class I would like to do this:

```
stop a service
reinstall a package
start the previous service again
```

Here is my class:

```
class MyClass{
    service{"ServiceName-start":
      name => "ServiceName",
      ensure => "stopped",
    }
    package{"PackageName":
        ensure => "installed",
        require => Service["ServiceName-Start"],
    }
    service{"ServiceName-Stop":
      name =>  "ServiceName",
      ensure => "running",
      require => Package["PackageName"]
    }
}
```

I got this error:

> Duplicate definition: Service[ServiceName] is already defined in file
>   /puppet/mycsass.pp at line 2; cannot redefine at /puppet/myclass.pp:9

Comment: I have no idea what puppet is; however, looking at the structure of `MyClass`, is the error due to the "ServiceName-start" and "ServiceName-Stop" services having the same `name => "ServiceName"`?

Comment: Yes, I would like the same service stop first and start later

Comment: Also, should `require => Service["ServiceNameStart"],` be `require => Service["ServiceName-start"],`?

Comment: @MetroSmurf Puppet is a deployment orchestration... thing.  I'm guessing that the OP wants to execute a sequence of actions, but is instead just defining the structure of something. A proper answer here would be pointing at the mechanism on sequencing actions in puppet I'm guessing, not rephrasing the error output

Comment: @MetroSmurf Thanks for the catch :). But it doesn't help the error

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be as simple as you'd like. [Here's a brief explanation of the problem in the Puppet User's group.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/puppet-users/UKTCghrs1Sw/jNoF4TFuP28J%20%22A%20brief%20explanation%20from%20the)

This quote sums the post up:

> Puppet is not a script engine, and its language is not a
>   scripting language.  You *can* write scripts in Puppet, but it is
>   cumbersome.  Puppet is all about achieving and maintaining particular
>   states of system resources, intentionally de-emphasizing the mechanism
>   for getting from here to there.  Thus, "how do I make Puppet perform
>   ?" is rarely a useful question.

The post author also offers an alternate (though less appealing solution) that I've adapted for your example:

```
class MyClass {
  exec { "ServiceName-Stop":
    command => "/bin/sh -c '/sbin/service ServiceName stop",
  }
  package{"PackageName":
    ensure => "installed",
    require => Service["ServiceName-Stop"],
  }
  service{"ServiceName-Start":
    name =>  "ServiceName",
    ensure => "running",
    require => Package["PackageName"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Not that this fixes anything but I think you've got the names of your services backwards. 'ServiceName-start' stops the service and 'ServiceName-Stop' starts it. My example labels them as the reverse of your example. If I'm wrong, un-reverse :)

Answer (score 0):

May be the virtual resources be useful here though I am not sure... The current structure of the two .pp files I am using are like the following :

```
/etc/puppet/modules/testmodule/manifests/init.pp
/etc/puppet/modules/testmodule/manifests/test.pp
```

init.pp looks like this; I have used mysqld for the service.

```
class testmodule {

  @service { "mysqld" :
    ensure => stopped,
  }

}
```

test.pp looks like this;

```
class testmodule::test inherits testmodule {

  realize(Service["mysqld"])

  package { "mysql" :
    ensure => installed,
    notify => Service["mysqld"],
  }

  Service["mysqld"] {
    ensure => running,
  }

  realize(Service["mysqld"])

}
```

In your site.pp you can do :

```
node 'my_nodename.com' {
   include testmodule::test
}
```

Hope this helps....